# HTML to XML and vice versa and validation with schema at run time from UI - JAXB?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, tinymce

I have a requirement which is probably a very common requirement across several companies.

Requirement: I have a rich interface UI. The UI elements which are represented are based on the schema. So every element has a way which it appears on the UI. For example,  element in the  schema occurs with a [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/) editor on the UI. Now, the user can add elements of a different type before or after the response element as per the schema. So the UI has to change accordingly. ON top of every element the UI gives two buttons "Add Before"/"Add After". So how do I deal with a scenario like this?

What is a good way to compute at run time based on changes in the UI as to why goes before or what goes after a particular element and how many times a particular element can be added?

Is there a way to do this requirement at all? I am assuming I have to come up with my own algorithm.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> What is a good way to compute at run time based on changes in the UI
>   as to why goes before or what goes after a particular element and how
>   many times a particular element can be added?

Use unique `@id` in both your XML and HTML and ensure that every element receives an `@id` value. Render the HTML from the XML with the `@id` for the corresponding content item.  That way, in for HTML front-end when you select the item that you want to insert content before/after you can send the `@id` of the element in an AJAX request and use that information to select the exact element in the XML on the back-end and update the HTML rendering.

Manipulating the HTML and XML could be done in a variety of ways.

There are commercial tools, such as [Xopus](http://xopus.com/xopus-web-based-wysiwyg-xml-editor.html), that allow you to build a WYSIWYG interface that enforces Schema constraints.

Comment: XOPUS demoed their tool. It is too client intensive and does not support the languages which we were looking for our product. I will try this out.